# TCP message is not written to file in windows C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcp, byte, streamwriter

I have these bytes:

```
1 68 78 77 51 51 49 32 49 50 49 51 48 55 13 10 71 71 32 69 89 86 73 89 68 89 88 13 10 49 50 49 51 48 55 32 69 89 86 73 90 80 90 66 13 10 2 71 79 79 68 32 68 65 89 44 13 10 68 73 83 82 69 71 65 82 68 32 84 72 73 83 32 65 82 82 32 77 83 71 32 66 69 76 79 87 13 10 40 65 82 82 45 76 89 84 73 84 47 65 55 48 49 51 45 69 89 86 73 45 69 89 86 73 49 50 52 54 41 13 10 86 78 79 32 66 82 73 69 70 73 78 71 13 10 11 3 84 32 49 50 48 53 13 10 45 83 83 82 67 79 68 69 32 65 55 55 49 51 13 10 45 83 69 81 85 69 78 67 69 68 65 84 65 13 10 45 84 88 84 73 77 69 32 50 48 48 56 49 50 49 51 48 52 49 56 13 10 45 78 85 77 32 52 54 13 10 11 3
```

another example:

```
1 68 78 77 51 51 54 32 49 50 49 51 49 55 13 10 70 70 32 69 89 75 65 89 68 89 88 32 69 89 86 73 89 68 89 88 13 10 49 50 49 51 49 55 32 69 85 67 72 90 77 70 80 13 10 2 40 68 69 80 45 76 89 70 84 71 45 69 89 75 83 49 51 48 56 45 69 89 75 83 45 68 79 70 47 50 48 48 56 49 50 41 13 10 11 3 49 83 50 32 68 79 70 47 50 48 48 56 49 50 13 10 32 82 69 71 47 89 76 67 83 68 32 69 69 84 47 69 80 87 87 48 48 49 53 32 67 79 68 69 47 53 48 50 67 67 68 32 82 86 82 47 50 48 48 32 79 80 82 47 66 84 73 32 79 82 71 78 47 69 86 82 65 66 84 73 79 13 10 32 80 69 82 47 67 32 82 77 75 47 80 72 79 78 69 32 67 84 67 58 32 48 48 51 55 49 54 55 55 56 56 52 50 54 41 13 10 11 3 51 54 32 69 71 78 77 13 10 45 80 66 78 47 65 49 66 49 67 49 68 49 76 49 79 49 79 50 83 50 32 68 79 70 47 50 48 48 56 49 50 32 82 69 71 47 72 65 76 83 66 32 69 69 84 47 69 86 82 82 48 48 51 57 32 69 89 86 76 48 48 51 57 13 10 69 83 65 65 48 48 52 50 32 69 75 68 75 48 49 49 48 32 69 68 86 86 48 49 50 52 32 69 72 65 65 48 49 52 51 32 69 71 84 84 48 50 48 49 32 67 79 68 69 47 52 55 49 69 69 49 32 82 86 82 47 48 55 53 13 10 79 80 82 47 87 90 90 32 79 82 71 78 47 69 68 68 70 87 90 90 88 32 80 69 82 47 67 32 82 77 75 47 84 67 65 83 41 13 10 11 3
```

DATA READ (ascii control characters are not visible here, so I am adding picture below, the part that matches requirements should be written to file):

```
DNM336 121317
FF EYKAYDYX EYVIYDYX
121317 EUCHZMFP
(DEP-LYFTG-EYKS1308-EYKS-DOF/200812)
1S2 DOF/200812
 REG/YLCSD EET/EPWW0015 CODE/502CCD RVR/200 OPR/BTI ORGN/EVRABTIO
 PER/C RMK/PHONE CTC: 0037167788426)
36 EGNM
-PBN/A1B1C1D1L1O1O2S2 DOF/200812 REG/HALSB EET/EVRR0039 EYVL0039
ESAA0042 EKDK0110 EDVV0124 EHAA0143 EGTT0201 CODE/471EE1 RVR/075
OPR/WZZ ORGN/EDDFWZZX PER/C RMK/TCAS)
```

[image]

and a program that listens to these bytes coming and writes them to files when they match condition:
the message starts with SOH (1 in bytes) ends with EYX (3 in bytes) and has STX in body (2 bytes)

when I test it on mac it seems to work fine for me, but we deploy on server on windows and there sometimes it seems like message doesn't get written...
there can come several messages in same bytes array. this is how my program looks like:

```js
class Program
    {
        private const string V_AFTN = "";
        private const string K_AFTN = "";
        private const string P_AFTN = "";

       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folderProduction = @"";
            string folderTesting = @"";

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            Parallel.Invoke(() => Run(folderProduction,  80,
                    "Production"),
                () => Run(folderTesting, configuration.GetValue<int>("PortSettingsTesting:Port"), "Testing"));
        }


        private static void Run(string folderName, int port, string env)
        {
            connection:
            try
            {
                string[] switchStrings = {V_AFTN, K_AFTN, P_AFTN};
                string pathString = "";
                string airportFolder = "";
                string fileName = "";
                TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
                
                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine(env + " TCP listener started on port: " + port);

                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(env + " Waiting for connection");
                        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                        Console.WriteLine(env +  " Connected!");
                        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
                        string result = null;
                        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                        Console.WriteLine("Buffer size: " + client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                        // Buffer for reading data
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                        while (stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) != 0)
                        {
                            var bytesArray = bytes.TakeWhile(x => x != 0).ToArray();
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesArray.Length; i++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(bytesArray[i] + " ");
                            }
                            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesArray);
                            Console.WriteLine("\r\n DATA READ: \r\n" + data);
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            for (int j = 0; j < bytesArray.Length; j++)
                            {
                                string byteToString = "";

                                if (result == null && (bytesArray[j] == 0 || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] {bytesArray[j]}))))
                                    continue;
                                
                                if (bytesArray[j] == 1)
                                {
                                    byteToString = "\x01";
                                }
                                else if (bytesArray[j] == 3 && result != null)
                                {
                                    byteToString = "\x03";
                                }
                                else if (bytesArray[j] == 2 && result != null)
                                {
                                    byteToString = "\x02";
                                }
                                else if (result != null)
                                {
                                    byteToString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] {bytesArray[j]});
                                }
                                
                                result += byteToString;

                                if (result.StartsWith("\x01") && result.Contains("\x02") && result.Contains("\x03"))
                                {
                                    switch (switchStrings.FirstOrDefault<string>(s => result.Contains(s)))
                                    {
                                        case V_AFTN:
                                            fileName = V_AFTN;
                                            break;
                   
                                        default:
                                            fileName = "Unknown";
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    
                                    pathString = Path.Combine(folderName, airportFolder);

                                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString))
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                                    }
                            
                                    var id = GenerateIncrementalId(folderName, fileName);
                                    CreateTextFile(pathString, fileName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd_hhmm") + $"_{id}" + ".txt",
                                        result);
                                    
                                    Console.WriteLine(env + " File created");
                                    result = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(env + " Finished");
                        // Shutdown and end connection
                        client.Close();
                    }

                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(env + " SocketException: {0}", e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // Stop listening for new clients.
                        server.Stop();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(env + " Failed to connect: " + e.Message);
                goto connection;
            }
        }

        private static int GenerateIncrementalId(string path, string airport)
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            var files = d.GetFiles("*.txt").Where(x => x.Name.Contains(airport));
            var fileInfos = files as FileInfo[] ?? files.ToArray();
            if (!fileInfos.Any())
            {
                // if there's no file yet, return 1
                return 1;
            }
            // return next incremental ID
            return fileInfos.Count() + 1;
        }

        private static void CreateTextFile(string path, string textTitle, string data)
        {
            var pathToWrite = Path.Combine(path, textTitle);
            if (!File.Exists(pathToWrite))
            {
                var charsToRemove = new [] {' ', '\n', '\r'};
                data = data.TrimEnd(charsToRemove);
                File.Create(pathToWrite).Close();
                using var sw = new StreamWriter(pathToWrite);
                Console.WriteLine("WRITING DATA: \r\n" + data);
                sw.WriteLine(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Writing data to: " + pathToWrite);
                data = null;
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

I know OS shouldn't be a problem but I'm stuck with this and don't know what could be wrong here

Comment: Your issue is with following like : while (stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) != 0).  TCP datagram are max size of ~1500 and servers and routes can spit and combine datagrams.  So a messages that are received can contain pieces of messages or more than one message.  Also TCP has a keep alive that contains zero bytes.  Your code must handle all these conditions.   Your working example probably is one hop and is seeing everything that gets sent and everything that gets received is the same size.  When going over multiple hops this is not always the case.

Comment: thanks @jdweng, I actually didn't know that... how should prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can't.  It is part of the TCP specification.